# Exercise ball as a complement

Tags: workout, home-exercise, exercise-ball

Since I work from home very long hours (9-12h) every day and do not have to conmute, I force myself to be constantly active.

I do swimming, bike riding and short workouts (30 min) at a gym 2-3 days a week. Normally I finish my workouts doing abs, and since I learned some moves with the exercise ball I only train them directly with the ball now.

Recently I am wondering if getting a ball for home will make a big difference.

One one side I want to replace my chair for a couple of hours, mostly to add some variety to my posture. On the other, I could forget about direct abs training at my gym and add some extra exercise. On the recovery days I could just do just some short-intense abs training separate from other exercises.

Is it worth the idea? Does is sound like a good thing to do? Could I overdo abs or hinder recovery by training that way? I always disregarded the ideas of home training and ball-chair but thinking about the sitting variety and moving off direct abs training from my gym seems quite sound.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this answer is way too late to help you at all but extra exercise in this form is certainly not going to hurt your goals. Having an exercise ball is definitely going to complement your physique with loads of exercises to do such as planks/crunches etc. I would recommend still hitting abs though as its going to get important as you progress more with deadlifts/squats if you do those exercises.